# How to Change BuddyPress Mystery Man Graphic without Overwriting Core Image File

Tags: buddypress

I am using Sarah Gooding's workaround to replace the core mystery man graphic with a custom graphic. It does not work. It continues to render the core mystery man graphic.

Has anyone had any success overwriting the mystery man graphic?

```
// Source: http://wpmu.org/how-to-add-a-custom-default-avatar-for-buddypress-members-and-groups/

function myavatar_add_default_avatar( $url ) {

    return get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/images/mystery-man.jpg';

}
add_filter( 'bp_core_mysteryman_src', 'myavatar_add_default_avatar' );
```

Tried this too (got it from http://etivite.com/api-hooks/buddypress/trigger/apply_filters/bp_core_mysteryman_src/).

It did not work either:

```
apply_filters( 'bp_core_mysteryman_src', 'myavatar_add_default_avatar' );
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used this code on my own BuddyPress site. Works like a charm!

```
// Use a better image than default mystery man
function bp_custom_set_avatar_constants() {
   define( 'BP_AVATAR_DEFAULT', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/mystery-man.jpg' );
   define( 'BP_AVATAR_DEFAULT_THUMB', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/mystery-man-50.jpg' );
}
add_action( 'bp_init', 'bp_custom_set_avatar_constants', 2 );
```

Add this to your [`bp-custom.php`](http://codex.buddypress.org/extending-buddypress/bp-custom-php/) file, or, if you're developing a theme, to your theme's `functions.php` file.

Comment: Your code is working but I had to disable Gravatar first with latest BuddyPress version using this PHP code: `add_filter('bp_core_fetch_avatar_no_grav', '__return_true');`.
The third parameter "2" is not necessary as well as the `bp_init` hook, why did you add them in your example? By the way, do you know why the hook `bp_core_mysteryman_src` used by the OP is not working? It looks like other people had this problem after a new BuddyPress version: https://buddypress.org/support/topic/how-to-change-your-mystery-man-image/#post-120755